# Execute Client Function from Server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, client

After looking into WCF, I don't believe it can do what I need it to. What would be the appropriate way (if I have a server and client application, both C# .NET Console apps) to basically instruct the client to execute functions?

For example, if the client application has functions such as DownloadFTPFile(), CreateWindowsService(), IsServiceRunning(), etc. what would be the standard approach to telling them to execute this from the client?

I was initially just going to have the client interpret messages sent from the server, such as "downloadfile ftp://filename.zip" but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I believe you need to look deeper at WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Client has Agent.
- Agent connects to server, polls for cmomands
- Agend executes comands.

THe server sending is tricky unless you control the environment. NAT for example makes "client sends" a nightmare. You also then open up the client for additional attacks with client polling the clietn firewall does not have tp open external access to the agent.

Comment: So something like this (http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/232473) is what I should look into? Server Push was what I had in mind, but I should basically have the clients continuously check the server for any new tasks?

Comment: That example is using .NET remoting, not WCF.

Comment: The question is how fast do you NEED to be. a Check of an agent every 15 seconds may be enough, maybe even every 300 seconds. You do not transport real time financial data to trading systems here.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Use the callback functions along with duplexes in the WCF. You will be limited to the intranet usage or azure though, since only NetTcpBinding and NetTcpRelayBinding support it (WsHttpBinding is deprecated).

Comment: Why only intranet/azure? NetTcpBinding is totally ok to be used on the internet, you know.

Comment: @TomTom: Yes, I know. You may use it over the internet, but since it uses binary encoding over the TCP, there is a high risk the communication would be blocked by the firewall (either on unknown port or packet contents), thus not making it totally ok. The other thing is that I can't imagine myself using of duplexes and callbacks over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

With WCF, any client can self-host a WCF service. This can make the client *be* a service. Add a little extra protocol between the client and the service, and you've got your wish.